# VBA Excel - Geo Coordinates from Address over Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, maps, coordinates

First of all tank you for all help here! nice place to be and learn a lot!

My Problem: I want to return Geo coordinates from an address. Like here: https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2014/06/geocoding-using-vba-google-api.html

I created an API Key and this code is working fine! But we have a Firewall and the Firewall is blocking Excel communication to the google maps server on the "request.send" point (and i couldn't find an IP Range or something that you can put on the whitelist), is there a chance to get the XML code by your browser? Because i can use the link from "Request.Open "GET" and i see the XML content in the Internet Explorer.
Is there any other way than request.send

Thank you guys!

Code:

```
Function GetCoordinates(Address As String) As String

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'This function returns the latitude and longitude of a given address using the Google Geocoding API.
'The function uses the "simplest" form of Google Geocoding API (sending only the address parameter),
'so, optional parameters such as bounds, language, region and components are NOT used.
'In case of multiple results (for example two cities sharing the same name), the function
'returns the FIRST OCCURRENCE, so be careful in the input address (tip: use the city name and the
'postal code if they are available).

'NOTE: As Google points out, the use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a limit of 40,000
'requests per month, so be careful not to exceed this limit. For more info check:
'https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet

'In order to use this function you must enable the XML, v3.0 library from VBA editor:
'Go to Tools -> References -> check the Microsoft XML, v3.0.
'If you don't have the v3.0 use any other version of it (e.g. v6.0).

'2018 Update: In order to use this function you will now need a valid API key.
'Check the next link that guides you on how to acquire a free API key:
'https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2018/02/how-to-get-free-google-api-key.html

'2018 Update 2 (July): The EncodeURL function was added to avoid problems with special characters.
'This is a common problem with addresses that are from Greece, Serbia, Germany and other countries.

'Written By:    Christos Samaras
'Date:          12/06/2014
'Last Updated:  09/08/2018
'E-mail:        xristos.samaras@gmail.com
'Site:          https://www.myengineeringworld.net
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Declaring the necessary variables.
'The first 2 variables using 30 at the end, corresponding to the "Microsoft XML, v3.0" library
'in VBA (msxml3.dll). If you use any other version of it (e.g. v6.0), then declare these variables
'as XMLHTTP60 and DOMDocument60 respectively.
Dim ApiKey          As String
Dim Request         As New XMLHTTP30
Dim Results         As New DOMDocument30
Dim StatusNode      As IXMLDOMNode
Dim LatitudeNode    As IXMLDOMNode
Dim LongitudeNode   As IXMLDOMNode

'Set your API key in this variable. Check this link for more info:
'https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2018/02/how-to-get-free-google-api-key.html
ApiKey = "Your API Key goes here!"

'Check that an API key has been provided.
If ApiKey = vbNullString Or ApiKey = "Your API Key goes here!" Then
    GetCoordinates = "Invalid API Key"
    Exit Function
End If

'Generic error handling.
On Error GoTo errorHandler

'Create the request based on Google Geocoding API. Parameters (from Google page):
'- Address: The address that you want to geocode.

'Note: The EncodeURL function was added to allow users from Greece, Poland, Germany, France and other countries
'geocode address from their home countries without a problem. The particular function (EncodeURL),
'returns a URL-encoded string without the special characters.
Request.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?" _
& "&address=" & Application.EncodeURL(Address) & "&key=" & ApiKey, False

'Send the request to the Google server.
Request.send

'Read the results from the request.
Results.LoadXML Request.responseText

'Get the status node value.
Set StatusNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//status")

'Based on the status node result, proceed accordingly.
Select Case UCase(StatusNode.Text)

    Case "OK"   'The API request was successful. At least one geocode was returned.

        'Get the latitude and longitude node values of the first geocode.
        Set LatitudeNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/geometry/location/lat")
        Set LongitudeNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/geometry/location/lng")

        'Return the coordinates as a string (latitude, longitude).
        GetCoordinates = LatitudeNode.Text & ", " & LongitudeNode.Text

    Case "ZERO_RESULTS"   'The geocode was successful but returned no results.
        GetCoordinates = "The address probably not exists"

    Case "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" 'The requestor has exceeded the limit of 2500 request/day.
        GetCoordinates = "Requestor has exceeded the server limit"

    Case "REQUEST_DENIED"   'The API did not complete the request.
        GetCoordinates = "Server denied the request"

    Case "INVALID_REQUEST"  'The API request is empty or is malformed.
        GetCoordinates = "Request was empty or malformed"

    Case "UNKNOWN_ERROR"    'Indicates that the request could not be processed due to a server error.
        GetCoordinates = "Unknown error"

    Case Else   'Just in case...
        GetCoordinates = "Error"

End Select
```

End Function     '

Answer (score 0):

You can try to detect the proxy settings and add these to the XMLHTTP request.

See this link for a good starting point (too much code to paste here): http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VB/microsoft.public.vb.winapi.networks/2004-11/0005.html